# How to disable a particular event handler from axon?

Tags: java, event-handling, axon

We have a few event handlers configured in the code. But, I'd like to disable a particular event handler from axon.

Please note - I can do this using @Profile or @Conditional parameter. But, I am interested to know if there is any way like config at EventConfig to exclude the particular event handler from processing.

Please refer below code.

Event Source Config

```
public class AxonConfig {
   
    public void configureProcessorDefault(EventProcessingConfigurer processingConfigurer) {
        processingConfigurer.usingSubscribingEventProcessors();
    }
}
```

Event handlers

````
@ProcessingGroup("this")
class ThisEventHandler {
    // your event handlers here...
}

@ProcessingGroup("that")
class ThatEventHandler {
    // your event handlers here...
}

@ProcessingGroup("other")
class OtherEventHandler {
    // your event handlers here...
}```
````

Answer (score 2):

The `EventProcessingConfiguration` that's constructed as a result of the `EventProcessingConfigurer` provides a means to retrieve your Event Processor instances. Furthermore, any `EventProcessor` implementation has a `start()` and `shutDown()` method.

You can thus stop the Event Processors that you want to stop.

The following piece of code would get that done for you:

```java
class EventProcessorControl {

    private final EventProcessingConfiguration processingConfig;

    EventProcessorControl(EventProcessingConfiguration processingConfig) {
        this.processingConfig = processingConfig;
    }

    public void startProcessor(String processorName) {
        processingConfig.eventProcessor(processorName)
                        .ifPresent(EventProcessor::start);
    }

    public void stopProcessor(String processorName) {
        processingConfig.eventProcessor(processorName)
                        .ifPresent(EventProcessor::shutDown);
    }
}
```

As a side note, I would warn against *only* using the `SubscribingEventProcessor`. Of the Event Processor implementations, it provides the least amount of flexibility when it comes to performance, distribution and error handling. I'd much rather try using the `PooledStreamingEventProcessor` instead.